# How can I insert increasing number into dynamically added HTML table rows?

Tags: jquery

I need to insert into commented by "HERE" section increasing numbers.
This is simple dynamically added table rows, and I want to number any row with numbers.

First row exist with number 1, so this should have number 2, another number 3 etc.

I've tried to use php ++ but it makes only second row number two, all of next rows have also number 2

```
$('#dodaj').click(function () {
    $('<tr class="tcent"><td class="tcent wauto"> /* HERE */</td><td><input class="w100 tcent" id="nazwa" type="text"></td><td><input class="w100 tcent" id="ilosc" type="text"></td><td><select id="miara" class="tcent"><option>szt.</option><option>l.</option><option>zest.</option></select></td><td><input class="w100 tcent" id="brutto" type="text"></td><td><input class="w100 tcent" id="netto" type="text"></td><td><input class="w80 tcent" id="podatek" type="text"> %</td><td class="tcent handy"><input type="button" id="usun" value="Usuń" /></td></tr>').appendTo('#towar');
});
```

Comment: Can you show your `++` usage? This appears to just be JS.

Comment: use a css counter?

Comment: I don't think this question is very clear, do you just want to add new rows to a table when a button is clicked or do you have a variable number of rows you are retrieving from a database? If (which I think) the first then you just need to count the number of rows the table already has ````$('"#table_id tr).length ```` or some such

Comment: @idzczakp. My Polish to English translation indicates that on the press of the Add button, a new row is created in the table with a number of input fields (Name, Measure, tax, etc.), and a Delete button at the end. What you are trying to achieve is to have the row number appear against each row in the table. Just edit your question to make this clearer. Include an example of what the table would look like after adding 3 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the last id globally then on each click increment it

```js
// var id = <?= $last_id + 1 ?>
var id = 123
$('#dodaj').click(function() {
  $(`
  <tr class="tcent">
    <td class="tcent wauto">${id}</td>
    <td><input class="w100 tcent" id="nazwa" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="w100 tcent" id="ilosc" type="text"></td>
    <td>
      <select id="miara" class="tcent">
        <option>szt.</option>
        <option>l.</option>
        <option>zest.</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="w100 tcent" id="brutto" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="w100 tcent" id="netto" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="w80 tcent" id="podatek" type="text"> %</td>
    <td class="tcent handy"><input type="button" id="usun" value="Usuń" /></td>
  </tr>`).appendTo('#towar');
  id++
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="dodaj">Add</button>

<table id="towar"></table>
```